# In nested router, I want the parent router to disappear when I click child router

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, react-router, react-router-dom

[image: three nested layer of react router]

top level:

```
export default () => {
  return (
    <Router initialEntries={['/home']}>
      <div className='app'>
        <div className='top'>
          <NavBar>配合路由使用</NavBar>
        </div>
        <div className='body'>
          <Routes>
            <Route exact path ='/home/*' element={<Home/>}>
             
            </Route>
            <Route exact path='/todo/*' element={<Todo/>}>
             
            </Route>
            <Route exact path='/message/*' element={<Message/>}>
              
            </Route>
            <Route exact path='/me/*' element={<PersonalCenter/>}>
              
            </Route>
          </Routes>
        </div>
        <div className='bottom'>
          <Bottom />
        </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
  )
}
```

home component:

```
import Sidebar from "./sidebar-link"
import './index.scss'
import Content from './content-router'
export default function Home() {
    return (
    <div className="connor-body-wrapper">
      <div  className="connor-sidebar-wrapper">
        <Sidebar/>
      </div>
      <div className="connor-content-wrapper">
        <Content  />
      </div>
    </div>)
  }
```

content compoent:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    MemoryRouter as Router,
    Route,
    Routes
} from 'react-router-dom'
import Menu from './content/menu';
import Nutrient from './content/nutrient';
import Thought from './content/thought';

export default function Content() {
  return (
        <Routes>
            <Route exact path='/menu' element={<Menu/>}/>
            <Route exact path='/nutrient' element={<Nutrient/>}/>
            <Route exact path='/thought' element={<Thought/>}/>
        </Routes>
    )
}
```

The parent router is the bottom tab; the child router is the left sidebar. When I click the child link (left side bar ), I want the parent router(the bottom tab ) UI to disappear, because I want to improve user experience with bigger screen by remove the parent UI .

Comment: Please also include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the relevant code you're working with. You should also have only 1 router per app. Can you also verify what routing/navigation package you are using? You tagged `react-router` but your UI looks like `react-navigation`.

Comment: @Drew Reese,thank you.i am using react-router-dom@6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are wanting to conditionally render the the bottom navigation/component depending on whether or not the user is on a root path or in a nested path. For this I suggest using layout components that render the UI and layout as you desire and renders nested `Route` components into an `Outlet`.

Read more about [Layout Routes](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/concepts#layout-routes)

The idea is to create 2 layouts, one with the bottom component and the other without.

```
const FullLayout = () => (
  <>
    <div className="body">
      <Outlet />
    </div>
    <div className="bottom">
      <Bottom />
    </div>
  </>
);

const BottomlessLayout = () => (
  <div className="body">
    <Outlet />
  </div>
);
```

Now you'll need to split up the route paths, the paths *exactly* matching the roots go into the `FullLayout` component, while the nested paths into the other.

```
<Router initialEntries={["/home"]}>
  <div className="app">
    <div className="top">
      <NavBar>配合路由使用</NavBar>
    </div>
    <Routes>
      <Route element={<FullLayout />}>
        <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/todo" element={<Todo />} />
        <Route path="/message" element={<Message />} />
        <Route path="/me" element={<PersonalCenter />} />
      </Route>
      <Route element={<BottomlessLayout />}>
        <Route path="/home/*" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/todo/*" element={<Todo />} />
        <Route path="/message/*" element={<Message />} />
        <Route path="/me/*" element={<PersonalCenter />} />
      </Route>
      <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/home" replace />} />
    </Routes>
  </div>
</Router>
```

Demo

[image: Edit in-nested-router-i-want-the-father-router-to-disappear-when-i-click-child-route]